# I need to change the Wordpress wp_ prefix to stop conflicts with other site on server

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I've developed a client's site in Wordpress and used multiple plugins. I've come to the stage where I need to copy the site to the clients server, but there's already a Wordpress blog on it (using the prefix wp_). I've read that whilst installing WP you can choose a different prefix for tables on the same DB as other WP builds (ie. 'wp_' to 'new_wp_'), however I wasn't aware of this other site when I started building the site for the client.

So now I need to change the prefix of my site's files site-wide, and I'm having issues. Has anyone come across this problem before, and if so what's the solution? I very much want to avoid having to do a fresh install, as I've done a lot of work in the admin section with plugins etc.

Any help would be great :)

Dalogi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've used the walk through at this link a few times to move/change the prefixes in the database for a live site or a move from localhost to live; it looks old, but they still work, according to the comments: http://tdot-blog.com/wordpress/6-simple-steps-to-change-your-table-prefix-in-wordpress

If you somehow have hardcoded links in theme files, you need to change those manually.

There is a plugin or two that also does the database table change: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/better-wp-security/

Answer (score 0):

See wp-includes/wp-db.php

```
$table_prefix = wpdb::get_blog_prefix();
```

And use that, instead of hard-coding it.

Answer (score 0):

According to the WordPress codex entry [Installing Multiple blogs](https://codex.wordpress.org/Installing_Multiple_Blogs), you need to set the `$table_prefix` value in the `wp.config` file.

```
$table_prefix = 'wp_'; // example: 'wp_' or 'b2' or 'mylogin_'
```

I've installed multiple WP instances using the same db with this method, and have never gotten a database conflict.